# using xunit2 in visual studio 2015. Test explorer does not display output

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dnx, test-explorer, xunit2

When I open the Test Explorer, I do not see my tests, even after a rebuild. I can run the tests using `dnx . test` and they run as expected.

My `project.json file` is listed below. I am using ASP.Net 5 beta6 with xUnit 2 and Visual Studio 2015 (beta 6).

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ClassLibrary1 Class Library",
  "authors": [ "jriegel" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.20",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0",
    "xunit": "2.1.0-beta3-*",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta3-*"
  },
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  }
}
```

Comment: what are your exact versions of xunit and xunit.runner.dnx packages? does it help to close ([x]) the test explorer window, rebuild and open it again (for me, this was the solution...)?

Answer (score 0):

The new [xUnit Visual Studio runner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio/) package is compatible with Visual Studio 2015 and integrates with the Test Explorer.

Just run

```
install-package xunit.runner.visualstudio
```

and rebuild the project. Test discovery will pick up everything in your project.

If anyone is having trouble even after installing the package, the runner [documentation](http://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-vs.html) lists a caveat:

> If you've previously installed the xUnit.net Visual Studio Runner VSIX (Extension), you must uninstall it first. The Visual Studio runner is only distributed via NuGet now. To remove it, to go `Tools > Extensions and Updates`. Scroll to the bottom of the list, and if xUnit.net is installed, uninstall it. This will force you to restart Visual Studio.